# Why this simple export is giving me error in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this `example product js` file and i am exporting it and using it in the `node routes`

```
let products = [
    {
      _id: "1",
      name: "Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
    },
    {
      _id: "2",
      name: "iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Memory",
    },
    {
      _id: "3",
      name: "Cannon EOS 80D DSLR Camera",
    },
  ];
  
  export default products
```

and i am getting that data in the server.js like this

```
const products = require('./data/products')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('api running')
})

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
    res.json(products)
})


app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    const product = products.filter(p => p._id === req.params.id);
     res.json(product);
});
```

but whenever i try to run the server i got this error `Unexpected token 'export'`.
Why this simple export is giving me error?

Comment: The problem is you're using ES Modules and, as far as I know, that's not natively supported by Node.js, you need to use something like Babel/Webpack for that. For it to work you need to use `module.exports = products`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use common js module syntax instead of es6 module syntax for exporting `products`:

```
module.exports = products;
```

Comment: Hi Your answer solve this problem. But i got a bonus question :D.
Right now this filter function is not working when I export as your answer giving me this error `products.filter is not a function`

Comment: Answer updated.